# Esconder o cerrar un formulario MDI Children

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms, formularios

Buenas , tengo un formulario MDI (frmPrincipal) donde abro un formulario MDI Children (frmListadoClientes).

Dentro de este mdi children al cerrar el formulario lanzo un formulario (frmOpciones) que permite hacer un par de gestiones rápidas que bien se puede pulsar una de ellas o cancelar el formulario.

- Si se cancela el frmOpciones se nos queda en modal el frmListadoClientes
- Si se acciona uno de los botones de frmOpciones se abre un 4º formulario (frmTPV) , por lo que intento esconder el tercer formulario (frmOpciones) y mostrar en forma modal este último formulario abierto , para ello uso este código

Código para abrir el formulario de Opciones

```
frmOpciones frm = new frmOpciones (param1 , param2);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Desde el formulario frmOpciones (3º formulario) abro la opción correspondiente para ello se abre  el 4º formulario que lo lanzo con este código

```
private void btnStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    Form f2 = new frmTPV(param1 , param2 , param3);
    f2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Aquí lo que intento hacer es que antes de lanzar este 4º form cierre el tercero pero no lo consigo , también he probado con un this.Hide() sin éxito.

El problema que tengo es este como hacer que no se muestre o quede escondido este formulario.

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema. Si desde `frmOpciones` muestras otro formulario modal, `frmOpciones` quedará deshabilitado por debajo del nuevo `frmTPV`. Porque quieres ocultar `frmOpciones`?

Comment: No se entiende la parte de **"desde el mdi children"**, es decir desde `frmListadoClientes`? Cuando lo **intentas** cerrar, **sin finalmente cerrarlo**, debe mostrarte en `.Modal` el `frmOpciones`? Y una vez seleccionado uno de los botones del `frmOpciones` se muestra en `.Modal` el `frmTPV`, ocultando el `frmOpciones`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, a mí me ha funcionado lo siguiente:

```
private void btnStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.Close();
    Form f2 = new frmTPV(param1 , param2 , param3);
    f2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    f2.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Ya me dices si te ha funcionado.

Saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

Buenas,

Lo que estas intentando hacer es como una ventana de menú dónde eliges que acción realizar y abrir una ventana u otra dependiendo del botón que se haga clic.

La forma mas sencilla de realizar esta acción es llamando al formulario frmOpciones des del frmPrincipal y dependiendo del botón que se haga clic, el mismo formulario devuelva una variable para que frmPrincipal la interprete y abra el formulario que se desea, y de ésta manera te aseguras que se va a abrir con ése MDI y frmOpciones estará cerrado:

Código para frmOpciones:

```
public int OpcionMenu { get; set; } //Declaramos una variable como property para recogerla en frmPrincipal.
```

Evento del click de TPV:

```
private void TPVbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpcionMenu = 1; //Número que asociarás al formulario que deseas abrir
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
}
```

Código para frmPrincipal:

```
int opcionMenu;
frmOpciones frm = new frmOpciones (param1 , param2);
frm.ShowDialog();
if (frm.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
   opcionMenu = frm.OpcionMenu; //Recogemos el valor de frmOpciones
   if (opcionMenu == 1)
   {
       //Abrimos el frmTPV
   }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.